# Powershell Script prompt user for input on validate set Function Parameter

Tags: powershell, validateset

I'm guessing this is impossible, but I figured I'd ask because it would be cool if I could.

I have a function, that has a validate set (so people don't screw up the input - obviously)
However, prompts in a script don't seem to allow for this.
I've looked all over, I can't find anyone asking this question, or providing any details that would help.

```
function ShowStackOverFlowCommunity-ExampleOfFunction {
    PARAM (
        
        [parameter()]
        [validateset(
            "Don't Input Incorrect Things",
            "Stop it",
            "I Swear to God..."
        )]
        [string]
        $pplbedumb

    )

    write-host "Hi I'm a script. TeeHee"
    write-host $pplbedumb;

}
```

So an example script would be

```
$path = read-host "input path to file"
$pathdata = gc $path;

foreach ($item in $pathdata) {
    get-service $item | select name, balls, etc. 
    if ($item.balls) {
        ShowStackOverFlowCommunity-ExampleOfFunction 
    }
}
```

I'm well aware that I can do a read-host - but that allows for the possibility of input mistakes.
The only thing i can think of is to just say at the beginning of the script "HEY, RUN THIS FUNCTION FIRST OUTSIDE OF THE SCRIPT. THEN COME BACK"

But that's just...lame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run your validation after the user put his input and then return a "Please try again" or "Please follow the restrictions for the input"

When I was writing a script to check the users without opening the AD console I did the below:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
[string[]]$GetADProps=echo Created, Name, EmailAddress, Enabled, LockedOut, LastBadPasswordAttempt, PasswordExpired, AccountExpires, PasswordLastSet, LastLogonDate, Modified, LogonCount, Office, TelephoneNumber
[string[]]$FlProps=echo Created, Modified, LogonCount, Name, EmailAddress, Enabled, LockedOut, PasswordExpired, PasswordLastSet, LastLogonDate, LastBadPasswordAttempt, Office, TelephoneNumber
do{
    $Username = (Read-Host -Prompt "Please Enter Username to Lookup")
    Get-ADDomainController -Filter * | Select Name, IPv4Address, Site | Sort-Object Name | Out-String
    $DC = (Read-Host  -Prompt "Please Enter the Domain Controler name from the list")
    $ADUser= Get-ADUser -Server $DC $Username -Properties $GetADProps  
    if ($adUser.'LockedOut' -or $ADUser.'PasswordExpired'){
    $ADUser | Format-List $FlProps  | Out-String | Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red
do {
    do {
        write-host ""
        write-host "[U] - Unlock User " -NoNewline; write-host "$Username" -ForegroundColor Red
        write-host "[R] - Reset Users " -NoNewline; write-host "$Username" -ForegroundColor Red -NoNewline; write-host " Password"
        write-host "[C] - Check Users " -NoNewline; write-host "$Username" -ForegroundColor Red -NoNewline; write-host " Account Info"
        write-host ""
        write-host "[X] - Exit"
        write-host ""
        write-host -NoNewline "Type your choice and press Enter: "
        
        $Choice = read-host
        
        write-host ""
        
        $ok = $Choice -match '^[urcx]+$'
        
if ( -not $ok) { write-host "Invalid selection" }
} until ( $ok )
```

So the user using it had to put the right input.
If you need to search a specific path you can run a `test-path` and if it is not right you can prompt the user again.

Also I read about the validate set on https://adamtheautomator.com/powershell-validateset/
Hope this helps you.